# Insert into custom index with JDBC River

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I'm trying to use ElasticSearch in conjunction with MySQL.  [JDBC River](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) seemed to be exactly what I wanted, but I can't get my data to insert anywhere other than `jdbc/jdbc` using:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/the_db",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "hunter2",
        "sql" : "select * from hamburgers",
        "index" : "the_db",
        "type" : "hamburgers"
    }
}'
```

I'd expect the data to be accessible at `localhost:9200/the_db/hamburgers` (from what I can clean from [the docs](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/JDBC-River-parameters)) but it's all in `localhost:9200/jdbc/jdbc`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that you are defining the river incorrectly. the proper way would be:

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/my_jdbc_river/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc" : {
        "driver" : "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "url" : "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/the_db",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "hunter2",
        "sql" : "select * from hamburgers",

    },
    "index" : {
        "index" : "the_db",
        "type" : "hamburgers"
    }
}'
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks so much.  I figured it was something like this.